# CSS Class is still displayed when CSS Display is set to none causing JScript ID issues

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a situation where I am stuck and do not know how to solve it.
I have a contact page that has some calculations that need to be processed and it will not work with Display: block and Display: none.

My Code is displayed below:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    .contactMobile{
        display: none;
    }
    
    .contactDesktop{
        display: block;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width : 667px) {

        .contactMobile{
            display: block;
        }
        .contactDesktop{
            display: none;
        }
        }
</style>


<section class="contactDesktop" id="contact">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <form asp-action="Contact" asp-controller="Home" method="POST" role="form" class="php-email-form">
            <input asp-for="Stats" type="hidden" value="99" />
            <table class="tg">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="tRow1">
                            contact Top Left
                        </td>
                        <td class="tRow2" rowspan="2">
                            <div class="form">
                                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                                    <div class="row contactDesktop" id="submit">
                                        <div id="chk">
                                            <div class="col-md-12" style="padding:10px!important;text-align:left;">
                                                <label class="text-lg-start">Add:</label>
                                                <input id="val1" style="max-width:30px;padding:5px;border:0;text-align:center;color:white" disabled>
                                                +<input id="val2" style="text-align:center;max-width:30px;padding:5px;border:0;color:white" disabled>
                                                =<input style="max-width:30px;padding:5px;" name="honey" id="honey" oninput="myFunction(this.value)">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="buttonCheck">
                                            <div class="col-md-12" style="padding:5px!important;">
                                                <div class="form-group sndBtn">
                                                    <button type="submit" style="border-radius:5px;">SEND</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <br />
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-12 form-group" style="color:red; font-size:large; font-weight: 600;">
                                            <div class="loading">Loading</div>
                                            <div class="error-message"></div>
                                            <div class="sent-message" style="background: darkgreen;border-radius:5px;">Your message has been sent. Thank you!<br />We will respond ASAP.</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="tRow3" rowspan="2">
                            Contact Right
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="tRow4">
                            Contact Bottom Left
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="contactMobile" id="contact">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-3 text-center" style="margin-top:25px;">
                Contact US
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6" id="contactUs">
                <div class="form">
                    <form asp-action="Contact" asp-controller="Home" method="POST" role="form" class="php-email-form">
                        <input asp-for="Stats" type="hidden" value="99" />                      
                        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                            <div id="submit" class="contactMobile row">
                                <div id="chkM">
                                    <div class="col-md-12" style="padding:10px!important;text-align:left;">
                                        <label class="text-lg-start">Add:</label>
                                        <input id="val1M" style="max-width:30px;padding:5px;border:0;text-align:center;color:white" disabled>
                                        +<input id="val2M" style="text-align:center;max-width:30px;padding:5px;border:0;color:white" disabled>
                                        =<input style="max-width:30px;padding:5px;" name="honey" id="honey" oninput="myFunctionM(this.value)">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="buttonCheckM">
                                    <div class="col-md-12" style="padding:5px!important;">
                                        <div class="form-group sndBtn">
                                            <button type="submit" style="border-radius:5px;">SEND</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br />
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12 form-group" style="color:red; font-size:large; font-weight: 600;">
                                    <div class="loading">Loading</div>
                                    <div class="error-message"></div>
                                    <div class="sent-message" style="background: darkgreen;border-radius:5px;">Your message has been sent. Thank you!<br />We will respond ASAP.</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var ranVal1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10), 2);
    var ranVal2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10), 2);
    var ranVal = Math.floor((ranVal1 + ranVal2), 2);
    $("#val1").val(ranVal1);
    $("#val2").val(ranVal2);
    $('#buttonCheck').css({ 'display': 'none' });

    function myFunction(val) {
        if (val == ranVal) {
            $('#buttonCheck').css({ 'display': 'block' });
            $('#chk').css({ 'display': 'none' });
            $("#Stats").val("200");
        }
    }
</script>
```

This only works to hide the desktop from view when I am in Mobile mode; however, the Math calculations are not working.  Upon a Chrome Inspection, I noticed that even though the Desktop code was not visible on my monitor, it was still present on the html code and is affecting the JavaScript because the IDs are doubled.

Is there another way for me to only show the html code that is meant for either the Desktop or Mobile?

Comment: `display:none` is not "removed from html", it's just not displayed.

Comment: I tried adding both visibility and display to my CSS at the same time to make sure, but it still does not work.  What would you recommend?

Comment: Neither of those css properties removes an element from the DOM. You'd need to use Javascript to remove the element(s), but in reality, all IDs should be unique.

Comment: Tks for your advice.  What I am trying to do requires the IDs to be the same and should only be available when the appropriate device is active.  I will try to use JavaScript to the delte the code that I do not need under these conditions to avoid having both set of code present at the same time.  Otherwise, I can also use JavaScript to write the code that I need for the device as well, but it is so much to write and I was afraid to mess things up between the quotes, etc.

Comment: You could use a class that's unique to the two inputs, then when you set the value it will go in both, but only one will be displayed/visible to the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but you can add an if/else statement in your javascript to check for your window size & display your forms based off of those values. You will likely not want to repeat **ID**s'. Be sure to add the appropriate classes to the divs' that should be hidden based on mobile or desktop layout.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    .contactMobile{
        display: none;
    }

    .contactDesktop{
        display: inline-block;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width : 667px) {
        .contactMobile{
            display: inline-block;
        }
        .contactDesktop{
            display: none;
        }
    }
</style>
<section class="contactDesktop" id="contact">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <form asp-action="Contact" asp-controller="Home" method="POST" role="form" class="php-email-form">
        <input asp-for="Stats" type="hidden" value="99" />
        <table class="tg">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <!--
                    <td class="tRow1">
                        contact Top Left
                    </td>
                    -->
                    <td class="tRow2" rowspan="2">
                        <div class="form">
                            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                                <div class="row contactDesktop">
                                    <div id="chk">
                                        <div class="col-md-12" style="padding:10px!important;text-align:left;">
                                            <label class="text-lg-start">Add:</label>
                                            <input id="val1" style="max-width:30px;padding:5px;border:0;text-align:center;color:#666" disabled>
                                            + <input id="val2" style="text-align:center;max-width:30px;padding:5px;border:0;color:#666" disabled>
                                            = <input style="max-width:30px;padding:5px;" name="honey" id="honey" oninput="myFunction(this.value)">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="buttonCheck" class="contactMobile">
                                        <div class="col-md-12" style="padding:5px!important;">
                                            <div class="form-group sndBtn contactMobile">
                                                <button type="submit" id="sendIT" style="border-radius:5px;">SEND</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>                                  
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <!--
                    <td class="tRow3" rowspan="2">
                        Contact Right
                    </td>
                    -->
                </tr>
                <!--
                <tr>
                    <td class="tRow4">
                        Contact Bottom Left
                    </td>
                </tr>
                -->
            </thead>
        </table>
    </form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 form-group" style="font-size:large; font-weight: 600;">
            <div class="loading contactMobile" style="color:#cc0000;">Loading</div>
            <div class="error-message"></div>
            <div class="sent-message contactMobile" id="sent-message" style="color:#fff;background: darkgreen;border-radius:5px;padding:10px;">Your message has been sent. Thank you!<br />We will respond ASAP.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="contactMobile" id="contactM">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <!--
            <div class="col-md-3 text-center" style="margin-top:25px;">
                Contact US
            </div>
             -->
            <div class="col-md-6" id="contactUs">
                <div class="form">
                    <form asp-action="Contact" asp-controller="Home" method="POST" role="form" class="php-email-form">
                        <input asp-for="Stats" type="hidden" value="99" />                      
                        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                        <div class="contactMobile row">
                            <div id="chkM">
                                <div class="col-md-12" style="padding:10px!important;text-align:left;">
                                    <label class="text-lg-start">Add:</label>
                                    <input id="val1M" style="max-width:30px;padding:5px;border:0;text-align:center;color:#666" disabled>
                                    + <input id="val2M" style="text-align:center;max-width:30px;padding:5px;border:0;color:#666" disabled>
                                    = <input style="max-width:30px;padding:5px;" name="honey" id="honey2" oninput="myFunctionM(this.value)">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="buttonCheckM" class="contactDesktop">
                                <div class="col-md-12" style="padding:5px!important;">
                                    <div class="form-group sndBtn contactDesktop">
                                        <button type="submit" id="sendITM" style="border-radius:5px;">SEND</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 form-group" style="font-size:large; font-weight: 600;">
                        <div class="loading contactDesktop" style="color:#cc0000;">Loading</div>
                        <div class="error-message"></div>
                        <div class="sent-message contactDesktop" style="color:#fff;background: darkgreen;border-radius:5px;padding:10px;">Your message has been sent. Thank you!<br />We will respond ASAP.</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
       </div>
    </div>
</section>

<script type="text/javascript">
var width = $(window).width();
var height = $(window).height();

if ((width >= 667) && (height>=768)){
    $("#honey").focus();
    var ranVal1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10), 2);
    var ranVal2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10), 2);
    var ranVal = Math.floor((ranVal1 + ranVal2), 2);
    $("#val1").val(ranVal1);
    $("#val2").val(ranVal2);

    function myFunction(val){
        if (val == ranVal) {
            $('#buttonCheck').show();
            $('.sndBtn').show();
            $('#chk').hide();
            $("#Stats").val("200");
            $(".loading").show().fadeOut('slow');
            $("#sendIT").on("click", function(){
                $(".sent-message").show();
            });
        }
     }
 }else{
     $("#honey2").focus();
     var ranVal1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10), 2);
     var ranVal2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10), 2);
     var ranVal = Math.floor((ranVal1 + ranVal2), 2);
     $("#val1M").val(ranVal1);
     $("#val2M").val(ranVal2);

     function myFunctionM(val) {
        if (val == ranVal) {
             $('#buttonCheckM').show();
             $('.sndBtn').show();
             $('#chkM').hide();
             $("#Stats").val("200");
             $(".loading").show().fadeOut('slow');
             $("#sendITM").on("click", function(){
                $(".sent-message").show();
             });    
          }
      }
  }
 </script>
```